# Watson Assistant Integrating with Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have integrated Watson assistant with Fb messenger. I  am able to send messages to the chatbot because i am an admin of the FB Page but How to make the chatbot Public so that any user on FB can send messages to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the page Live

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow others to access your assistant you need to submit it to Facebook for review. The process is pretty simple you just provide a few things the assistant can respond to and wait for someone to review.